# What is this syntax: template tplname{op(id,[id2])}(params)

Tags: templates, syntax, operator-overloading, curly-braces, nim-lang

In the json module:

```
template simpleGetOrDefault*{`{}`(node, [key])}(node: JsonNode, key: string): JsonNode = node.getOrDefault(key)
```

What's up with the curly braces (and what's that in them) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a ["term-rewriting macro"](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#term-rewriting-macros).

A bit earlier in the json module, you'll find the definition of the `{}` operator with the following signature:

```
proc `{}`*(node: JsonNode, keys: varargs[string]): JsonNode =
  ## Traverses the node and gets the given value. If any of the
  ## keys do not exist, returns ``nil``. Also returns ``nil`` if one of the
  ## intermediate data structures is not an object.
```

The goal of the term-rewriting macro is to intercept the case where only a single string is given as argument to the operator and to turn this into a simple call to `getOrDefault`.